# Excel VBA: How to sum every row above?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a formula which does the following:
sum all rows above this one until row 3. (Row 1 and 2 are headers). This code has to go from columns E:AQ, What gets tricky for me is that the row with the last line varies monthly. This month it is row 133, next month it could be 145. Here is my code so far:

```
Sub Fsum()
Dim Rng1 As Range
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Actuals")
Set Rng1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(x1Up)
.Range("Rng1:AQ").Formula = "=sum(???lines above???)"
End Sub
```

You can see where I get confused. Can someone help?

Comment: When a row shows `#REF`, are all of the cells in that row `#REF`?  And is it the only place that `#REF` is expected to be in your worksheet?

Comment: Yes, all the cells are #REF in that row. Now that I'm thinking over my code, I think I can just delete the row with #REF and sum everything above without making an IF statement, but I still am not sure how to code it so It sums all quantities above

Comment: @Jarom I have edited the code accordingly

Comment: I'm a tad confused. Are you trying to sum all of the values in column E from 3 to the last row (and have that value below the last row in column E), F from 3 to the last row (and have that value below the last row in column E), etc, all the way to AQ 3 to the last row  (and have that value below the last row in column E)?

Comment: @sous2817 sorry If I was confusing. I want the sum to be below the last row of whatever column it is. Ex: Sum F from 3 to the last row (and have that value below the last row in column F), sum G from 3 to the last row (and have that value below the last row in column G), and so on until AQ

Comment: One note is that #REF!, I personally hate the errors and always use something like IFERROR formula to output something that is more meaningful.  Maybe this doesn't apply your situation anymore but thought about to mention it from your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to go about it:

```
Sub test()
Dim lr As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Actuals")

With ws
    lr = .Cells(1, 5).EntireColumn.Find(what:="*", _
            After:=.Cells(1, 5).EntireColumn.Cells(1), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row

    Range(.Cells(lr + 1, 5), .Cells(lr + 1, 43)).Formula = "=Sum(E3:E" & lr & ")"
End With

End Sub
```

This will find the last used cell in Column E (5 in the code) and set that as the overall last row.  Then it will build a sum formula across to column AQ (43 in the code).

Each time you run the code, it will find the last row.  So it should be fairly dymanic.  If each column has a different last row, that can be done as well, just need to use a loop, but I got the impression that your last row will be different from report to report, not column to column.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT***

Here is an alternate way of finding the last row in case the one above gives you problems:

```
Sub test()
Dim lr As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Actuals")

With ws
    lr = ws.Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range(.Cells(lr + 1, 5), .Cells(lr + 1, 43)).Formula = "=Sum(E3:E" & lr & ")"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So I tried this code and got: Run time Error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Yes the sheet is called Actuals

Comment: the error comes here: `lr = .Cells(1, 5).EntireColumn.Find(what:="*", _
            After:=.Cells(1, 5).EntireColumn.Cells(1), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Row`

Comment: yeah, I can't see what would be wrong w/ that.  Are you copying in my entire code and running it?  Or just taking the parts between the 'With ws'?

Comment: @cthallofamer  I added in an alternate way of getting the last row.  See if that works any better for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! The alternate code you put isn't changing anything in my worksheet.... Which seems odd.

Comment: @cthallofamer  Sorry, my test sheet had a different worksheet name than what you have.  I've edited that to match (Changed it to 'Actuals').  If that doesn't work, what's the value of LR before the formula gets written?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find the #REF! first and here is something for your reference to find the cell.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindRef()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim RefRng As Range

Set Rng = Range("A1:F100") ' Use your own range
Set RefRng = Rng.Find(what:="#REF!", LookIn:=xlValues)

MsgBox "Found the #REF! " & RefRng.Column & RefRng.Row

End Sub
```

Comment: After you find the `#REF!`, using parts of the above code (assuming that only one row has `#REF!` in the entire worksheet),  use this to sum the range. `Sum = Application.Sum(Range("A1:A" & rng1.Rows))`